# 2-manifold with boundary l = 2

Tags: manifolds, manifolds-with-boundary

Can someone help me figure out what a 2-manifold with l=2 boundary would look like?

Can it simply be a closed disk with double boundary? I'm new to topological data analysis and I know this is a very easier question, I have just been stuck at it for a wile considering the boundary definition. If anyone can help, thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $l-2$ connected components for the boundary? For example, if you look at the closed disk, its boundary is a circle which is made of one connected component. If you take many disjoint disks you will get one connected component for the boundary for each disk.

Comment: @frog Sorry, that was a typing error, it’s l = 2. Yes, a closed disk is a 2-complex with zero genus but I’m confused about what would be an example for something with two boundaries, since I’m having trouble discerning whether l = 2 represents two boundaries. And if so, I can’t think of an example for that. Also, thank you.

Comment: Your question is unclear: what does it mean "l=2 boundary"? Do you mean a surface whose boundary consists of two components? There will be infinitely many such surfaces even if you restrict to compact and connected ones.

Comment: I believe it's a manifold with 2 boundaries, such as a half torus.